# Nlog Reference not found

Tags: reference, visual-studio-2017, nlog

I get this error, I tried clean solution and restoring package, but it didn't work.

[image]

Comment: Please add some more info. There could be thousand reasons why this isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. Just run this command on VS command prompt:

regsvr32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSEnv\VsLangproj.olb"

[(REF)](http://richardschneider.net/blog/wordpress/?p=21)